# how to keep group by(WORKERDEPT) value on second page in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am having problem in displaying group by page break value(WORKERDEPT) on second page because when i print the report the group by value is not showing and so Reportitems!WORKERDEPT.Value placed in header shows the blank value because of moving to page 2.

please help and if you need more detail then i can provide
thank you
regards

Comment: Do you want to load it in just 1 page? but if the your report is loading so many pages that's not a recommended solution I think.

Comment: i am trying to see WORKERDEPT value on each page of a report using reportitem expression.

Comment: So you want to see the group header on each page? Click on the tablix >>  open advanced mode. Find the static that relates to the row you want and in properties set KeepWithGroup to After and RepeatOnNewPage as true.

Comment: Thanks a lot thats worked :)